# Create Indexer in VB.NET which can be used from C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, indexer, language-interoperability

Can I create a class in VB.NET which can be used from C# like that:

```
myObject.Objects[index].Prop = 1234;
```

Sure I could create a property which returns an array. But the requirement is that the index is 1-based, not 0-based, so this method has to map the indices somehow:

I was trying to make it like that, but C# told me I cannot call this directly:

```
   Public ReadOnly Property Objects(ByVal index As Integer) As ObjectData
        Get
            If (index = 0) Then
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            End If
            Return parrObjectData(index)
        End Get
    End Property
```

**EDIT**
Sorry if I was a bit unclear:

C# only allows my to call this method like

`myObject.get_Objects(index).Prop = 1234`

but not

`myObject.Objects[index].Prop = 1234;`

this is what I want to achieve.

Comment: `Default` is the keyword that you're missing. Brian's answer has got you covered.

Comment: You are asking for an indexed property, which is a feature not directly available in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fake named indexers in C# using a struct with a default indexer:

```
public class ObjectData
{
}

public class MyClass
{
    private List<ObjectData> _objects=new List<ObjectData>();
    public ObjectsIndexer Objects{get{return new ObjectsIndexer(this);}}

    public struct ObjectsIndexer
    {
        private MyClass _instance;

        internal ObjectsIndexer(MyClass instance)
        {
            _instance=instance;
        }

        public ObjectData this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance._objects[index-1];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Main()
{
        MyClass cls=new MyClass();
        ObjectData data=cls.Objects[1];
}
```

If that's a good idea is a different question.

Comment: Important to note that this is a good solution only if your ObjectData object is a class.  If it's a struct, you won't be able to store a reference to it in ObjectsIndexer (at best you can get a copy).  This makes using this pattern to wrap unsafe structs with fixed buffers problematic, because you can't use fixed buffers in a class and you can't have a  ObjectsIndexer pointing to a struct.

Answer (score 16):

The syntax is:

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index as Integer) As ObjectData
  Get
    If (index = 0) Then
      Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
    End If
    Return parrObjectData(index)
  End Get
End Property
```

The `Default` keyword is the magic that creates the indexer. Unfortunately C# does not support named indexers. You are going to have to create a custom collection wrapper and return that instead.

```
Public ReadOnly Property Objects As ICollection(Of ObjectData)
  Get
    Return New CollectionWrapper(parrObjectData)
  End Get
End Property
```

Where the `CollectionWrapper` might would look like this:

```
Private Class CollectionWrapper
  Implements ICollection(Of ObjectData)

  Private m_Collection As ICollection(Of ObjectData)

  Public Sub New(ByVal collection As ICollection(Of ObjectData))
    m_Collection = collection
  End Sub

  Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal index as Integer) As ObjectData
    Get
      If (index = 0) Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
      End If
      Return m_Collection(index)
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

Comment: And if I want the property to have a name other then Item?

Comment: You forgot the "property" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't support the declaration of *named* indexed properties (although you can create indexers), but you can access indexed properties declared in other languages (like VB) by calling the setter or getter explicitly (`get_MyProperty`/`set_MyProperty`)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of the 0 based indexing but give the illusion to the coder that it is 1 based?

ie

```
Return parrObjectData(index-1)
```

Comment: How should the method signature look like?

Comment: The same as it is, this should be the only line that should change. Apart from removing the (index = 0) if statement block

Comment: But my problem is that with the current method signature, VB.NET doesn't allow me to call the method like myObject.Objects[index]