# VB.Net to C# conversion errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax-error

I am working on a SSIS job which has a script task in VB.Net. Our organizational directive is to move towards C# in the long run. For a new SSIS job I am developing, I used an online VB.Net to C# converter and using it in a scrip task. The VB.Net statement that reads a variable has similar syntax in C#, but throwing an error message. Below is the VB.Net and the equivalent C# code.

VB.Net statement:

```
Dim strEnvironment As String = Dts.Variables.Item("g_Environment").Value.ToString()
```

C# statement:

```
String strEnvironment = Dts.Variables.Item("g_Environment").Value.ToString()
```

As you can see, the statement to store a value in a variable is same between VB.Net and C#. However, when I use this code in the script task of SSIS job, the C# code is flagging the below error message.

```
'Variables' does not contain a definition of 'Item' and no accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'Variables' could be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).
```

My import statements have the following:

```
Using System;
Using System.IO;
Using System.text;
Using Sytsem.Collections;
Using System.Data;
Using Microsoft.Visualbasic;
Using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
```

I am completely new to SSIS/VB.Net and C#. Can someone help?

Comment: Maybe it should be `Dim strEnvironment as String` in VB instead of `String strEnvironment `.

Comment: `Dts.Variables["g_Environment"]`

Comment: @ErrBon, sorry, my bad in that syntax error. It was Dim strEnvironment As String only. I changed the OP.

Comment: @Chetan, It kinda helped. I had to use Dts.Variables["g_Environment].ToString(); Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the converter you used could determine that Item seems to be a default property, not a method (function, in vb terms), or it didn't understand how to translate it to C#

VB has `( )` for both methods and collections(arrays)

```
Dim array = "a,b".Split(",")      'method, args are surrounded in ()
Dim a = array(0)                  'indexer also is surrounded in ()
```

C# has `( )` for methods and `[ ]` for accessing indexable collections by some indexer:

```
var array = "a,b".Split(",");     'method, surrounded by ()
var a = array[0];                 'indexer, surrounded by []
```

For classes that represent a collection, there might be provided an indexing property in VB - property (of any name) marked with `Default` that is the property accessed when no other property name is specified. In C# the equivalent property is always called `this` and you don't get to choose the name, nor do you specify it when you index the item

Your VB:

```
Dim strEnvironment As String = Dts.Variables.Item("g_Environment").Value.ToString()
```

Could also have been:

```
Dim strEnvironment As String = Dts.Variables("g_Environment").Value.ToString()
```

But as it's indexing, you use `[]` with it in C#:

```
String strEnvironment = Dts.Variables["g_Environment"].Value.ToString();
```

---

By the way, modern Visual Studio helps you with props vs methods:

[image]

..methods are yellow, properties are white and local variables are light cyan.. (But there isn't anything that shows in intellisense that shouts "this thing is indexable")

If you write `.Something(...)` and see that it's white, then Something is a property, not a method

Also, class names are green, dim stuff is unused and 3 dots mean theres a suggestion for something that could perhaps be improved

Comment: FYI, the issue is `Item` not `Items` (not sure if you meant to refer to `Variables`, though the problem doesn't indicate if it's a function or a property) and `Item` is the automatic indexer for VB (interestingly enough, you'll even see it in reflection).

Answer (score 1):

`Item` is the indexer in VB.  The direct equivalent of `Item(x)` in VB is `[x]` in C#.

I'm a little surprised that a converter would not be aware of this (or that it would be confused by e.g. calling a function with the empty parameter list omitted).

Also see this question for more information on indexers: [Create Indexer in VB.NET which can be used from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992029/create-indexer-in-vb-net-which-can-be-used-from-c-sharp)