# C# equivalent to VB's "System.Data.DataRow.Item"?

Tags: c#, vb.net, datarow

I'm trying to find an equivalent of VB's "System.Data.DataRow.Item" but I can't find one.  I'm re-writing VB code to C# and I'm new to C#.  Noob question, probably.  I figured you guys would have some good insight.  The code snippet is below.  I found another stack overflow post with a similar question but the answers weren't helpful to me so I'm posting this.

Here's the error as well: `Error    CS1061  'DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```cs
...
// C# code                         
if (Reader.HasRows) // check that data exists
{
    var winshare = new DataTable();
    winshare.Load(Reader);
    foreach (DataRow row in winshare.Rows)
    {                                
        string path = row.Item["List_Item"]; 
        path = path + @"\Out";
        GlobalVariables.pwc = row.Item["Sublist_Id"];
...
```

```vb
...
// VB code  
If Reader.HasRows Then // check that data exists
    Dim winshare As DataTable = New DataTable
    winshare.Load(Reader)
    For Each row As DataRow In winshare.Rows
        Dim path As String = CStr(row.Item("List_Item"))
        path = path + "\Out"
        pwc = CStr(row.Item("Sublist_Id")) // Used to determine archive path also
...
```

Comment: Please try: `row.Item["Sublist_Id"];` It's a C# array. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-6.0

Comment: @MarkusMeyer It's not an array, it's an indexer.  But, as with VB, it uses the same access as if it were an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VB.Net to C# conversion errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768151/vb-net-to-c-sharp-conversion-errors)

Comment: My apologies, I actually did change from parentheses(I'll edit on the original post to avoid more confusion)  But unfortunately, I'm still getting the exact same error when using the indexer brackets [] @Craig

Comment: @MarkusMeyer My apologies, I actually already did change the indexing brackets. (I changed in the original post to avoid confusion) But I'm still getting the same error, even with correct indexing brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VB has default properties and C# has indexers. In VB, you can specify the default property explicitly, e.g.

```vb
pwc = CStr(row.Item("Sublist_Id"))
```

or implicitly:

```vb
pwc = CStr(row("Sublist_Id"))
```

C# indexers are basiclly the same as the implicit option:

```vb
pwc = (string)row["Sublist_Id"];
```

In either language, I would tend to recommend a bit of LINQ to DataSet anyway:

```vb
pwc = row.Field(Of String)("Sublist_Id")
```

```cs
pwc = row.Field<string>("Sublist_Id");
```

Comment: While I have you here, why do I no longer need the ```row.Item``` like in VB and instead just use ```row["Sublist_Id"]``` in C#?  I'm a little confused on that tbh. @user18387401

Comment: I told you in the answer. Did you read it? There is no `Item` property in C# because C# uses indexers. If you don't know what C# indexers are, read the documentation on the subject.

Comment: I know what indexers are intuitively but perhaps not as deep as I thought.  I'll read up on them.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you need to use brackets [] not parens () as they aren't used in this fashion.

```cs
row["List_Item"].ToString();
```

The Item method appears to be there otherwise.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-6.0

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error with the correct indexing brackets.

Comment: The item would likely come back as an object so you would need to convert it to a string like you are doing in VB

Comment: That being said I would typically not use the .Item and just go for row["List_Item"].ToString() less typing that way.

Comment: Turns out ```(string)row["Sublist_Id"];``` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: When adding the .Item it gave me red squigglies.