# How to optimize my code and what's the VB.NET equivalent of C# indexers?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, matrix, structure

```
struct Matrix {
  readonly int Rows, Columns;
  int[,] _Matrix;

  public Matrix(int Rows, int Columns) {
    this.Rows = Rows;
    this.Columns = Columns;
    _Matrix = new int[Rows, Columns]
  }

  public Matrix(int RowsOrColumns) {
    this.Rows = RowsOrColumns;
    this.Columns = RowsOrColumns;
    _Matrix = new int[RowsOrColumns, RowsOrColumns]
  }

  public int this[int Row, int Column] {
    get => _Matrix[Row, Column];
    set => _Matrix[Row, Column] = value;
  }
}
```

I wrote a `Matrix` structure in C#. I was trying to write the same `Matrix` structure with VB but I can find VB equivalent of indexer(`int this[int Row, int Column]`). Is defining indexer in VB possible? How to define indexer in VB if it's possible?

```
Structure Matrix
  Private ReadOnly Rows, Columns As Integer
  Private _Matrix As Integer(,)

  Public Sub New(ByVal Rows As Integer, Columns As Integer)
    Me.Rows = Rows
    Me Columns = Columns
    ReDim _Matrix(Rows, Columns)
  End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal RowsOrColumns As Integer)
    Me.Rows = RowsOrColumns
    Me Columns = RowsOrColumns
    ReDim _Matrix(RowsOrColumns, RowsOrColumns)
  End Sub
End Structure
```

One more question! I aim to specify the sizes of `_Matrix`(two-dimensional array) in `Matrix(ByVal Rows As Integer, Columns As Integer)` or `Matrix(ByVal RowsOrColumns As Integer)`(constructor methods). I use `ReDim` to do it. Is there a better way to do this or is my way good to do it?

Comment: Please only one question per question. Regarding the indexer question, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992029/create-indexer-in-vb-net-which-can-be-used-from-c-sharp

Comment: You could use `_Matrix = New Integer(RowsOrColumns -1, RowsOrColumns - 1) {}`. VB.NET uses the index of the last element of the array instead of the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

The VB equivalent of a C# indexer is a Default Property:

```vb
Default Public Property Item(ByVal Row As Integer, ByVal Column As Integer) As Integer
    Get
        Return _Matrix(Row, Column)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _Matrix(Row, Column) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

See also:

- [How to: Declare and Call a Default Property in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property)
- [Default properties in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/293215/880990)